# Appcelerator studion freezes at workspace launcher screen

Tags: ios, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator

I am trying to install AppC 4.10 on mac os sierra but it gets stuck at workspace launcher screen and doesnt show to next screen.

I tried reinstalling all the things more than twice now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this link:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8877

> To unblock you from this situation, please follow the below instructions
>
> 1. Go to /Applications/Appcelerator Studio/configuration/.settings
> 2. Open org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs file in any editor
> 3. Set SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=false by default it's true.
>
> This will avoid the workspace prompt dialog and open the studio directly.

Comment: Thanks for quick help, I cant find org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs in configuration folder.I have installed 4.10 on Mac

Comment: ".settings" folder is a hidden folder

Try going there using the terminal: 
    "cd /Applications/Appcelerator\ Studio/configuration/.settings" 

and then use nano to edit the file

Comment: JDK 1.9 is not yet supported by Appcelerator Studio, please use JDK 1.8 while you're working studio 4.10.0

Answer (score 3):

I was having jdk 8 and 9 both installed.I removed jdk 9 and it started working.

Appcelerator should improve their studio installation process.

Followed below url: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8877

It may help some of you for other issues.

Comment: I found one more issue while using sdk 5.5.1, if you are using node is 4 with appcelerator studio 4.1 then it gets stuck. I got it resolved after updating node js to 6.1

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
sudo npm cache clean
sudo rm -rf .appcelerator
sudo npm -g install appcelerator
appc use latest
appc setup

Open a Finder window and do the following:
Command+Shift+G - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
delete JDK
Install javaforosx (you can get the link by trying to open Appcelerator Studio)
Install JDK 8u151
```

Hope this helps!

Solution inspired from here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-8898?attachmentOrder=desc

Comment: I had the same problem but when i deleted the jdk-9.0.1.jdk its worked good